# Class method inherits list from its previous execution (Python)

Tags: python, class, graph-theory

See full working directory here: https://github.com/sharpvik/python-libs/tree/alpha/Testing

So I was working on some Graph theory and coding stuff in Python. I created a class called Graph as follows (don't worry about indentation, in the file itself it's fine):

```
class Graph:                                            # undirected graph; no values for the edges;
def __init__(self):
    self.nodes_counter = 0
    self.nodes_dict = dict()

def node_add(self, name):                           # name(int / str) -- name of the node;
    self.nodes_dict.update( { name : list() } )
    self.nodes_counter += 1
    return name

def node_del(self, name):                           # name(int / str) -- name of the node;
    self.nodes_dict.pop(name, None)
    for each in self.nodes_dict:
        self.nodes_dict[each].remove(name)
    self.nodes_counter -= 1
    return name

def connection_add(self, one, two):                 # one(int / str) and two(int / str) -- two nodes you want to connect;
    self.nodes_dict[one].append(two)
    self.nodes_dict[two].append(one)
    return [one, two]

def connection_del(self, one, two):                 # one(int / str) and two(int / str) -- two nodes you want to disconnect;
    self.nodes_dict[one].remove(two)
    self.nodes_dict[two].remove(one)
    return [one, two]

def nodes_count(self):                              # --> function returns the number of nodes in the graph;
    return self.nodes_counter

def nodes_return(self):                             # --> function returns the whole dict containing nodes and their connections;
    return self.nodes_dict

def node_return(self, name):                        # name(int / str) -- name of the node you're checking;
                                                    # --> function returns connections of the given node;
    return self.nodes_dict[name]

# search

## --> breadth first search using class Queue
def bfs( self, final, queue=Queue(None), checked=list() ):      # final(int / str) -- name of the node you're trying to establish connection with;
                                                                # queue(class Queue) -- Queue containing the element you are beginning with (format: element);
                                                                # checked(list) -- leave empty *** internal use ***;
                                                                # --> function returns True if the two nodes are connected, otherwise it returns False;
    if queue.length() == 0:
        return False
    temp = queue.pop()
    if temp == final:
        return True
    else: 
        checked.append(temp)
        for child in self.node_return(temp):
            if child not in checked:
                queue.ins(child)
        return self.bfs(final, queue, checked)
## breadth first search using class Queue <--

## --> depth first serach using class Stack
def dfs( self, final, stack=Stack(None), checked=list() ):      # final(int / str) -- name of the node you're trying to establish connection with;
                                                                # stack(class Stack) -- Stack containing the element you are beginning with (format: element);
                                                                # checked(list) -- leave empty *** internal use ***;
                                                                # --> function returns True if the two nodes are connected, otherwise it returns False;
    if stack.length() == 0:
        return False
    temp = stack.pop()
    if temp == final:
        return True
    else:
        checked.append(temp)
        for child in self.node_return(temp):
            if child not in checked:
                stack.add(child)
        return self.dfs(final, stack, checked)
## depth first serach using class Stack <--
```

The `bfs` and `dfs` functions in the end rely on my other two classes:

```
class Stack:
def __init__(self, element):
    if isinstance(element, list):
        self.storage = element
    else:
        self.storage = [element]

def add(self, element):
    self.storage.append(element)
    return element

def pop(self):
    temp = self.storage[-1]
    self.storage.pop(-1)
    return temp

def length(self):
    return len(self.storage)
```

and

```
class Queue:
def __init__(self, element):
    if isinstance(element, list):
        self.storage = element
    else:
        self.storage = [element]

def ins(self, element):
    self.storage.insert(0, element)
    return element

def pop(self):
    temp = self.storage[0]
    self.storage.pop(0)
    return temp

def length(self):
    return len(self.storage)
```

Now, in another file I've initialized a new `Graph` that I called `g` for simplicitiy and tested on it.

```
print("BFS for 1 and 2 # --> should return True")
print( g.bfs(2, Queue(1) ), end="\n\n" )

print("BFS for 1 and 4 # --> should return True")    # but returns False!!!
print( g.bfs(4, Queue(1) ), end="\n\n" )
```

Now, when I started debugging it, I've noticed that the `checked` list that keeps track of checked nodes for some reason stays full of the nodes checked by the first call to the function, even though I have implicitly set it to be `checked=list()` in the `def bfs(...)` declaration so that it will be empty every time someone calls the function. This unusual behaviour causes it to not check the node 4 because it thinks that it had already been checked (`checked = [1, 3, 4]`), therefore the second time function decides that two nodes aren't connected and returns False.

This problem can be solved if I pass `[]` empty list after the `Queue(1)` like that:

```
print( g.bfs(4, Queue(1), [] ) )
```

However this would complicate things and I also just want to know why it does that anyways. So if anyone knows what the hell is happening here, I am looking forward to your response.

Comment: (Meta advice: it's best not to edit voting commentary into questions. Add a comment instead, explaining _why_ you believe it is not a duplicate, and remember that an experienced poster made that decision in good faith. Avoid all caps when representing your view please.)

Comment: @halfer ok, sorry, I was stressed out. You're right.

Comment: No worries - even long-standing users here sometimes get a vote or close they don't like. It happens `:-)`